# Adding a plug to a direct wire vent hood

Tags: electrical, kitchens

I inadvertently bought a range vent hood that is a direct wire model instead of a plug in.  Is there any reason why I couldn't run a grounded replacement plug with a wire to the unit in lieu of the direct wiring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the plug and the corresponding outlet are sufficient for the hood's power requirements, there's no problem hard-wiring a plug to it. No different than hard-wiring a plug to a dishwasher or other appliance.